# Plugins that can do the same something like wedding video

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, montage

Does anyone know is there any plugins out there that can do something similar like those photo montage in video form for wedding? But it's in HTML5 or jQuery plugins.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: 1) Requests for plugin recommendations are off topic for SO 2) I'm pretty sure there's nothing in JS that will be able to do this.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I didn't know it's off topic.

Answer (score -1):

check this one :

https://tympanus.net/Development/PhotoDesk/

if not what you are looking for, can you plz provide a screenshot or a link?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I tried to send you a PM but somehow I couldn't find that option. It's something like this https://player.vimeo.com/video/69812671 I will have a few static images but I need to make it something like a video.

Comment: welcome, check this :
https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/index4.html
it can be a start point.